# Ideapad 330 touchpad double tap issue

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

After installing Ubuntu 18 LTS my touchpad work just fine except for the double tap to open things (double left click), the curious thing is that if I tap it 3 times it detects as 2 taps.
One tap to select and physical double click are working just fine.

I searched here looking for the same problem but the only thing I found was some people with touchpads not working at all.